# Getting "can't add a new key into hash during iteration"

Tags: ruby, key

I have a hash whose key is a number and whose value is an array. Given a number `boundary`, I'd like to adjust all keys in my hash that are greater than `boundary`.

I tried this:

```
header_info_hash.each do |k, v|
  if boundary < k
    val = header_info_hash[k]
    header_info_hash.delete(k)
    header_info_hash[k-1] = val
  end
end
```

but it raises an error:

```
RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration
```

What is an easier way to do this?  Note that I would like to make the changes to this data structure as opposed to creaeting a new one.

Comment: Not clear at all what you mean by "adjust all keys".

Comment: I missed that. I actually was wondering why you had removed it. Removed it back.

Comment: @sawa: the very same tag description suggests that we use `[ruby-hash]`, but I've never seen a question where it'd bring any value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is an easier way to do this?

Never ever modify a collection you're iterating. (unless you know precisely why you must do it). Instead, clone/dup the collection. You now have two copies of the same thing. Iterate one, but modify the **other**.

When you're done, replace the original with the modified copy (optional, subject to requirements).

In this case, it's not necessary to clone the hash before iterating and then delete keys from it. You can just build a new hash, with all keys already "adjusted" (whatever that means).

```
new_header_info_hash = header_info_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), result|
  if boundary < k
    result[k-1] = v
  else
    result[k] = v
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you following the OP's big mistake to call `header_info_hash[k]` when that can be referred to as simply as writing `v`?

Comment: @sawa: ah, I just applied some formal transformations, without reading too much into the code. :) Thanks.

Comment: I guess you also need to assign the value to the new hash even when the key does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: @sawa: right you are. If you find one more, I'll delete this sloppy answer (or maybe just the code) :)

Comment: I shoudl have mentioned in my quesiton I'd like to make edits to the original data structure, so I assume after I run the above I should run "header_info_hash = new_header_info_hash" to get everything back the way I want it?

Comment: @Natalia: yep, pretty much.

Comment: @Natalia: No, `header_info_hash = new_header_info_hash` will *not* make any changes to the original data structure. It will only make changes to the variable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: ah, right, of course. I was assuming that all access goes through that variable.

Comment: I'm confused by this last exchange.  I have a hash, "header_info_hash", that I want altered in the way I described in teh question.  Can I run "header_info_hash = new_header_info_hash" at the end of Sergio's code or not?

Comment: @Natalia: depends on who else uses this hash. If this is a local variable, created just before, then you can. If, on the other hand, `header_info_hash` is a method (or otherwise other parts of code reference this hash object), then simply reassigning the reference will not update these other references (they'll still point to the old object). Which is to say, this won't update the data structure in-place. It creates a _new_ data structure and then points this reference to a new place.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, taht definitely clears things up.  How do I apply the changes to the existing data structure?

Comment: @Natalia: [Hash#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace), for example